# MySQL Case in Update

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case

I've browsed the forums.  I've tested several different methods.  I just can't get this to work.

## GOAL:

Update the next column if an answer exists in the previous column

Q1 IS NULL at this point and I want it set to 1

Q2 IS NULL and I want it to stay NULL if Q1 IS NULL, If Q1 has an answer, update this column to 1

## PROBLEM:

Both columns always update to 1

## ATTEMPTS:

```
UPDATE Story1_Responses 
SET Q1 = IFNULL(Q1,'1'),  
Q2 = CASE WHEN Q1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE '1' END 
WHERE UserID = 16

UPDATE Story1_Responses 
SET Q1 = IFNULL(Q1,'1'),  
Q2 = CASE WHEN IFNULL(Q1,'') = '' THEN NULL ELSE '1' END 
WHERE UserID = 16

UPDATE Story1_Responses 
SET Q1 = IFNULL(Q1,'1'),  
Q2 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(Q1, '') = '' THEN NULL ELSE '1' END 
WHERE UserID = 16

UPDATE Story1_Responses 
SET Q1 = IFNULL(Q1,'1'),  
Q2 = CASE WHEN Q1 IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE IFNULL(Q2,NULL) END 
WHERE UserID = 16
```

## THOUGHTS:

It seems to me that MySQL updates the first column prior to the second column being evaluated even though they are in the same update statement execution.

Comment: "Q2 IS NULL and I want it to stay NULL if Q1 IS NULL, If Q1 has an answer, update this column to 1" -- what if `Q2 IS NOT NULL`? Leave it untouched?

Comment: There's also the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function.

Comment: Correct Peter, ultimately I have 10 columns, and I just want them to keep their value if they have one, otherwise either be null if the previous question does not have a response, or update if it's the next question in the queue.

Comment: Thanks tadman.  I just tried Q2 = IF(Q1 IS NULL, NULL, IFNULL(Q2,'1')) as well as Q2 = IF(Q1 IS NULL, NULL, IFNULL(Q2,'1')), but both of those set Q2 = '1' as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is important. First set Q2 (because it checks the previous value of Q1), then set Q1.

```
UPDATE Story1_Responses 
SET Q2 = CASE WHEN Q1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE '1' END,
    Q1 = IFNULL(Q1,'1')
WHERE UserID = 16;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46fa3/1)

Comment: Thank you Peter, that is, indeed, the case.  It's completely different than how SQL Server would handle it.  I should have thought about rearranging the order given my #THOUGHTS section.  One of those days I guess.